# Measure Theory Book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

What book should I use for measure theory?I have solved Rudin's Principle Of mathematical analysis up to chapter 7.Some people advised me to use Real and complex analysis by Rudin, while other said it must be stein and shakarchi.I'm confused , please help.

Comment: I quite liked [Folland](http://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Modern-Techniques-Applications/dp/0471317160/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1406917388&sr=8-1) but I'm sure there are many good texts.

Comment: Measure Theory by Pal Halmos is quite good, in my opinion.

Comment: I quite like Terence Tao's [Introduction](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf).

Comment: What are you looking for in the book? There is no way to objectively evaluate the answers to "what should I use"; it's just an opinion poll.

Comment: Try looking at Bogachev's book. It has a good collection of problems.

Answer (score 2):

My top three:

1. [Folland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160), lots of good problems; good chapter on probability; applications to other fields.
2. [Tao](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf), most enjoyable to read, IMO.
3. [Wheeden and Zygmund](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824764994), written by one of the masters; abstract, but forgiving introductory chapters.